# I want to add images dynamically in the wordpress sidebar

Tags: wordpress, image

I have created one blog.In that blog there are many posts.I want to add images into the sidebar.Images of sidebar are different per post but sidebar is common per post.So how can I add images dynamically to the sidebar? I have put the static images right now.
My link is: http://jaxonlabs.com/10-ways-start-brand-no-experience/

Comment: Where is the image source? Media library or comes from other site?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to achieve what you need:

1. Install the Custom Sidebars plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-sidebars/

2. Create a sidebar (with required images) corresponding to each post/page
3. Select the side bar to display for individual posts/pages

HTH.

Comment: But this way, you need to create a sidebar for each post/page right?

Comment: Is there any other option?Because there are many posts in my blog.I think It is not right way.

Comment: If I have 3 or 4 pages that is ok. But there are 20 or more posts in my blog page